# Why does my python script, which imports the docker-py package (linked below), give an error rather than running my docker container?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

I'm trying to use https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html to make a python script which runs my container.

After installing the package (it is imported using `import docker` and my image is called 'janus'), this is my python script:

```
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
client.containers.run("janus")
```

When I run the script, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/milanlakhani/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/timeout.py", line 124, in _validate_timeout
    float(value)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timeout'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_docker_python_sdk.py", line 3, in <module>
    client.containers.run("janus")
  File "/home/milanlakhani/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docker/models/containers.py", line 803, in run
    detach=detach, **kwargs)
  File "/home/milanlakhani/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docker/models/containers.py", line 861, in create
    resp = self.client.api.create_container(**create_kwargs)
  File "/home/milanlakhani/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 429, in create_container
    return self.create_container_from_config(config, name)
  File "/home/milanlakhani/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docker/api/container.py", line 439, in create_container_from_config
    res = self._post_json(u, data=config, params=params)
  File "/home/milanlakhani/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 289, in _post_json
    return self._post(url, data=json.dumps(data2), **kwargs)
  File "/home/milanlakhani/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/milanlakhani/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 226, in _post
    return self.post(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
  File "/home/milanlakhani/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 581, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/home/milanlakhani/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/milanlakhani/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/milanlakhani/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/milanlakhani/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 587, in urlopen
    timeout_obj = self._get_timeout(timeout)
  File "/home/milanlakhani/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 302, in _get_timeout
    return Timeout.from_float(timeout)
  File "/home/milanlakhani/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/timeout.py", line 154, in from_float
    return Timeout(read=timeout, connect=timeout)
  File "/home/milanlakhani/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/timeout.py", line 94, in __init__
    self._connect = self._validate_timeout(connect, 'connect')
  File "/home/milanlakhani/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/timeout.py", line 127, in _validate_timeout
    "int, float or None." % (name, value))
```

Maybe I'm missing something extremely obvious since I'm a beginner but in the docker-py docs I couldn't see why this shouldn't work. (I didn't think I need to set environment variables such as `DOCKER_HOST`, `DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY`, `DOCKER_CERT_PATH` because I'm running docker on my machine in the normal way as far as I'm aware.)

Please let me know if you need more details, I can also send the Dockerfile used to build the image, which exposes ports and has command

```
CMD /usr/bin/janus -o --configs-folder=/usr/local/share/ct-camera/janus
```

However, I have tried other images and an image name which includes the repo and the error is always the same regardless of the image!

I have also tried other commands from this package but the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading the version of my requests package from 2.22 to 2.15, using `pip3 uninstall requests` and `pip3 install requests==2.15`, solved this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to supply your correct Image name - somehing like:

```
client.containers.run("myrepo.com/janus")
```

and make sure to have the latest `requests` package:

```
pip3 install -U requests
```

Comment: Hi LinSel, thanks for the answer, neither of these do the trick - I updated requests and also have tried using a proper repository and tag and also tried other images, but I get the same error each time regardless of my image.

Comment: Also any ideas on the bonus question?

Comment: @MilanLakhani Don't add "bonus questions". Open a new questions. StackOverflow policy is to be focused. One question, one issue. StackOverflow is not a forum to *discuss* technologies. It's a Q&A where you provide a *specific* problem and other users provide a specific answer.

Comment: Thanks LinSel, I see that the requests site-package threw the initial error maybe this  is why you made the suggestion, actually it was downgrading requests that did the trick.

Comment: Makes sense Giacomo